# How can I create polgyon primitives aligned to the world

Tags: mesh, objects, transform-orientation

I saw some tutorials on Youtube and those meshes are always created along z-axis like

[image]

but I always get this:
[image]

How can I add meshes like that except for changing my orientation of view to xy-plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the mesh, press <kbd>T</kbd> to open up the Tools panel. In the operator menu at the bottom, deselect *align to view*.

[image]

Comment: There's an option for the default in user preferences also.